# Using equal height of css class using flexbox when parent is already using flex to justify content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have mulitple rows of 3 columns. In each column there is a main content `SavedSearchBox-content` (has different permutations, so height can differ) and a footer `SavedSearchBox-footer`

I am using flexbox so that I can use 3 columns and have space between, so only the middle column has space horizontally.

This is my HTML structure of a sample row with 3 columns with 3 permutations.

- With Pill and button
- No pill, no button
- With pill, no button

```
<div class="SavedSearches-wrapper">
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content">
      <h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a longer title for testing</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tag line</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount">
        <div class="Pill">4 New</div> <strong>searches</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer"><a class="Button ">Subscribe to this Alert</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content"><h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a title</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tagline</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer">
      <div class="RadioListToggler SavedSearchBox-Toggler">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="RadioListToggler-Link">Change alert frequency</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content"><h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a title</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tagline</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount">
        <div class="Pill">6 New</div> <strong>searches</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer">
      <div class="RadioListToggler SavedSearchBox-Toggler">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="RadioListToggler-Link">Change alert frequency</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css, the wrapper is using flex and justify content.

```
.SavedSearches-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.SavedSearchBox {
    max-width: 340px;
    width: calc((100%/3) - 64px);
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-content {
    padding: 22px 22px 0px 22px;
}
```

My question is, is there a way that all `SavedSearchBox-content` have equal heights without compromising the 3 column layout with `space-between`? I would prefer not to us a javascript solution if possible.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnexu6md/11/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is NO css mechanism to equalise heights of elements that do not share a parent.

Answer (score 0):

No I think there is no way to equalise the height of the elements with just using css. But you can use simple jquery code to make it work.

```
 function kb_equal_height_two() {
  var highest_element_two = 0;

  // Lösche die Höhe
  $('.SavedSearchBox-content').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });

  // Prüfe, welches Element am höchsten ist
  $('.SavedSearchBox-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > highest_element_two) {
      highest_element_two = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  // Weise diese Höhe allen Elementen zu.
  $('.SavedSearchBox-content').each(function() {
    $(this).height(highest_element_two);
  });
};
var resizeTimer_two;
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer_two);
  resizeTimer_two = setTimeout(kb_equal_height_two, 1);
});
```

Just add an load event for equalise the height when the page is loaded.
https://jsfiddle.net/sqk8howx/1/

-> just works if you resize the window

Answer (score -2):

Im  a big fan of Flex, but once Is started dabbling in [css-grid](https://learncssgrid.com/), I have learned that it is WAY more powerful than Flex for positioning, and obviously grids.

so heres what I did:

```
.SavedSearches-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.SavedSearchBox {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

I changed `display: flex` to `display: grid`.
`grid-template-columns:` lets me define the columns. You wanted 3 columns so I gave it `1fr 1fr 1fr`. The `fr` means fraction. so I split the grid into 3 fractions.
I added a `grid-column-gap`, thats the gap in-between each grid element and is easy to change.

I added padding to the grid-container to keep the elements from going edge to edge.

I removed all width restrictions from the `SavedSearchBox` element as the width is defined by the parent `SavedSearches-wrapper` under `grid-template-columns`.

That being said I think this is what you are trying to achieve, see [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdu7b92r/2/)

(Don't forget to add your webkit prefixes to ensure it works cross browser.)

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.SavedSearches-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /* CHANGE TO GRID */
    display: grid;
    /* DEFINE THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS (1fr is 1 fraction) */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /* DEFINE COLUMN GAP */
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    /* ADD PADDING TO ENTIRE CONTAINER IF YOU DONT WANT IT EDGE TO EDGE */
    padding: 1rem;
}

.SavedSearchBox {
  /* REMOVE WIDTH LIMITS HERE */
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-content {
    padding: 22px 22px 0px 22px;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #353535;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-tagline {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #999999;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-searchLink {
    color: #ee4900;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-propertyCount {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.Pill {
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ee4900;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.SavedSearchBox .SavedSearchBox-footer {
    border-top: 1px dashed #d8d8d8;
    padding: 10px 18px 12px 18px;
}

.Button {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ee4900;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    outline: 0px;
    margin: 0 0;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: 60px;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s, height 0ms 0ms, opacity 600ms 0ms, opacity 600ms 0ms;
}

.RadioListToggler {
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    line-height: 1.38;
}

.RadioListToggler-Link {
    color: #ee4900;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="SavedSearches-wrapper">
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content">
      <h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a longer title for testing</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tag line</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount">
        <div class="Pill">4 New</div> <strong>searches</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer"><a class="Button ">Subscribe to this Alert</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content"><h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a title</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tagline</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer">
      <div class="RadioListToggler SavedSearchBox-Toggler">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="RadioListToggler-Link">Change alert frequency</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-content"><h1 class="SavedSearchBox-title">This is a title</h1>
      <p class="SavedSearchBox-tagline">This is a tagline</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="SavedSearchBox-searchLink">This is a link</a>
      <div class="SavedSearchBox-propertyCount">
        <div class="Pill">6 New</div> <strong>searches</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SavedSearchBox-footer">
      <div class="RadioListToggler SavedSearchBox-Toggler">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="RadioListToggler-Link">Change alert frequency</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did the space between go?

Comment: This in no way answers the question being asked which is to equalise the heights 
 of **internal** elements. *"is there a way that all `SavedSearchBox-content` have equal heights "*